# Insert Query for table

Tags: sql, for-loop

How to add data from one table to another table with new data in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You'd use an SQL INSERT INTO SELECT like so:

```
INSERT INTO "table1" ("column1", "column2", ...)
SELECT "column3", "column4", ...
FROM "table2"
```

You can find more info here:
http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlinsert.html

Comment: tried this query but when execute again duplicate rows created

Comment: Yes, if you execute the same query, with hardcoded values,  you will get the same record inserted.  If you want a better answer then you need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough points to comment, but lomaxx's query is functioning correctly @shanks. If you run an insert query again, you will get duplicates for each time the query is run.

Comment: table structure is UsrID UserName Date Time

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. Sounds like you want to insert _new_ records from another table. That's a whole different answer.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO "table1" ("column1", "column2", ...) 

SELECT "column3", "column4", ... 

FROM "table2" 

minus

SELECT "column1", "column2", ... 

FROM "table1"